# How to set the default day to the coming saturday and sunday using JQuery datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am quite new to JQuery, i have failed to find the correct method to solve my problem.

So here are the codes I have written:

```
$(function() {
         $("#from").datepicker({
                    //dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                        minDate: 0,
                    defaultDate: "+1w",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    numberOfMonths: 1,
                        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'], 
                    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
                        $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                    }
                });

                $("#to").datepicker({
                    //dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                        minDate: 0,
                    defaultDate: "+1w",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    numberOfMonths: 1,
                        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
                    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
                        $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
                    }
                });
});
```

I want to set the "#from" textbox to the closest coming Saturday (the date) if today is before saturday and "#to" text box to Sunday (date), otherwise, put Sunday (date) in both textbox as the default day.

ex. today is 02/27/2013 (wednesday), i want to put 03/02/2013 in "#from" and 03/03/2013 in "#to", if today is 03/02/2013, i want to put 03/03/2013 on both text boxes.

I thought of creating a variable currDay and store today's date to it. Since days in datepicker goe from 0-6, and then i will calculate the difference between the current day and the coming saturday/sunday, then set the default date to currDay + diff

How do i go about doing that?

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the current day of the week, you can subtract that number from the position in the week to get your desired outcome:

```
$(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getDay();

    var from=6-n;
    var to=7-n;

    if(n==0)
        from=0;

    $("#from").datepicker({
        //dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        minDate: 0,
        defaultDate: "+"+from+"d",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });

    $("#to").datepicker({
        //dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        minDate: 0,
        defaultDate:  "+"+to+"d",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6WHyK/

Answer (score 0):

I probably didn't clarify my question well...thanks r0m4n for trying. I manage to figure this out by myself. If you paste the following codes in your js section, you will see what I was trying to do...

```
function toDay() {
    var date = new Date();
    var currDay = date.getDay();
    var diff = 7 - currDay;
    return (diff);
}


$(function () {
    var saturday = new Date();
    var sunday = new Date();
    sunday.setDate(sunday.getDate() + toDay());
    if (toDay != 0) {
        saturday.setDate(saturday.getDate() - 1 + toDay());
    } else {
        saturday = sunday;
    }
    var comingSaturday = (saturday.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + saturday.getDate() + '/' + saturday.getFullYear();

    var comingSunday = (sunday.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + sunday.getDate() + '/' + sunday.getFullYear();
    $("#from").val(comingSaturday);
    $("#to").val(comingSunday);
})
```

And of course, I'm new....i might have made some mistakes, please feel free to pick errors for me. Thanks again.